# qiskit: IQFT acting on subsystem of reversed-ordered qubits state

Tags: qiskit, programming, quantum-fourier-transform

I have a state `psi` as an ndarray of shape (`2 ** 3`,) s.t.

`psi[0]= amplitude of 000`

`psi[1] = amplitude of 001.`

So my qubit ordering is reversed w.r.t. qiskit's. To initialize the circuit correctly and apply the IQFT on the first 2 qubits from the left I tried the following code:

```
import qiskit as qt
from qiskit.aqua.circuits import FourierTransformCircuits as QFT

    circuit = qt.QuantumCircuit(3)
    circuit.initialize( psi, [i for i in reversed(circuit.qubits)])

    QFT.construct_circuit(circuit=circuit, qubits=circuit.qubits[:2], inverse=True)

    backend = qt.Aer.get_backend('statevector_simulator')
    final_state = qt.execute(circuit, backend, shots=1).result().get_statevector()
```

From the tests I've run, `final_state` is not what I expected: defining

`exact = np.kron(IQFT_matrix(2),np.eye(2)).dot(state)` with IQFT_matrix(2)= IQFT_matrix for 2 qubits.

```
np.testing.assert_array_almost_equal(final_state, exact)
```

fails. Can you please help me find the problem?

Comment: Bits order is reversed on IBM Q. The most significant bit is on the right.

Comment: I know, that's why I initialized using reversed(circuit.qubits). Am I converting this the wrong way?

I do not want to remap the state directly, since in future implementation the state will be many dimensional and I do not want to occupy tons of memory or perform a lot of operations on it.

Answer (score 0):

There is the parameter `do_swaps` when you construct the fourier transform circuit.

```
do_swaps (bool): Boolean flag to specify if swaps should be included to align
                 the qubit order of input and output. The output qubits would
                 be in reversed order without the swaps.
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. I've tried using this flag but it does not solve the problem: 'final_state' differs from what I expected not only for index mapping, but for values too.

Answer (score 0):

To change the endianness of a circuit in Qiskit you can use the `reverse_bits` method of the `QuantumCircuit`. To do so for the QFT you can pick the QFT from the circuit library, reverse it, and add it to your circuit:

```
from qiskit import QuantumCircuit
from qiskit.circuit.library import QFT

iqft = QFT(3, inverse=True)  # get the IQFT
reversed_bits_QFT = iqft.reverse_bits()  # reverse bit order

circuit = QuantumCircuit(3)
circuit.compose(reversed_bits_QFT, inplace=True)  # append your QFT
```